# Upgrading site collection to SharePoint 2013 taking long time

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, site-collection, upgrade

I m upgrading a site collection from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. Content DB size is 50GB and the upgrade job is running for more than 12 hours now. Is this normal?

The upgrade status page is showing "Upgrade In Progress". There are no errors so far and only 15 warnings.

Is there a way I can see progress using powershell?

Comment: What does SQL Profiler and/or SSMS Activity Monitor indicate for that particular database?

Comment: Yes Activity Monitor is showing some activity but I don't know which particular area to look at. Screenshot given below.

http://i.imgur.com/d57pTZu.jpg

Comment: I noticed that memory usage on SharePoint machine is 94% (time service is taking this memory). May be this is the cause of slowness. I read on another site below about same issue and one user is saying that we can restart time service and it will resume from where it left. But I am afraid to do that.

http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/02/04/how-to-perform-a-sharepoint-2013-site-collection-upgrade-with-powershell.aspx

Comment: 62 hours and upgrade is still running.